# What does "<domain>" refer to in the following example HTTP POST?

Tags: http-post, amazon-kinesis

What does "<domain>" refer to in the following example HTTP POST?

Surely the host should not literally be "kinesis.<region>.<domain>", but the article makes no mention of what region and domain are specifically.

**Please provide a couple of literal examples for an actual "Host:" line.**

```
    POST / HTTP/1.1
    Host: kinesis.<region>.<domain>
    Content-Length: 
    User-Agent: 
    Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
    Authorization: 
    Connection: Keep-Alive 
    X-Amz-Date: 
    X-Amz-Target: Kinesis_20131202.PutRecord
    {
      "StreamName": "exampleStreamName",
      "Data": "XzxkYXRhPl8x",
      "PartitionKey": "partitionKey"
    }
```

A link to the entire article is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html#API_PutRecord_Examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you are following is actual HTTP request being posted. 
And [domain simply](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ak_region) is `amazonaws.com`, whereas regions could be `us-west-1` or `us-west-2` etc etc based on which region you are using.

So, the endpoint or what they call `"host"` would look something like `kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

Read moe at [AWS Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ak_region)

Now, to put an event in the kinesis-stream, I use CLI which is cool and easy,

```
aws kinesis put-record --stream-name GregorSamsa --partition-key gregor-samsa --data "whatever" --region us-west-2 --profile aws-credentials
{
    "ShardId": "shardId-000000000000", 
    "SequenceNumber": "49572068906441151838856607979148753861106406028656771074"
}
```

And too see what actual http request it posts run it in the --verbose mode,

```
$ aws kinesis put-record --stream-name GregorSamsa --partition-key gregor-samsa --data "whatever" --region us-west-2 --profile aws-credentials --debug
2017-04-16 19:48:34,993 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/1.11.66 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/15.6.0 botocore/1.5.29
2017-04-16 19:48:34,994 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['kinesis', 'put-record', '--stream-name', 'a0135-GregorSamsa', '--partition-key', 'gregor-samsa', '--data', 'whatever', '--region', 'us-west-2', '--profile', 'aws-credentials', '--debug']
2017-04-16 19:48:34,994 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_scalar_parsers at 0x103039938>
2017-04-16 19:48:34,994 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_assume_role_provider_cache at 0x102d9ac08>
2017-04-16 19:48:34,994 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Skipping environment variable credential check because profile name was explicitly set.
2017-04-16 19:48:34,994 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /Users/as18/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/data/kinesis/2013-12-02/service-2.json
2017-04-16 19:48:34,998 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.kinesis: calling handler <function register_retries_for_service at 0x1029992a8>
2017-04-16 19:48:34,998 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: kinesis
2017-04-16 19:48:34,999 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.kinesis: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x103043a28>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,002 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /Users/as18/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/data/kinesis/2013-12-02/waiters-2.json
2017-04-16 19:48:35,003 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - OrderedDict([(u'stream-name', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x1033c7110>), (u'data', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x1033c7150>), (u'partition-key', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x1033c7190>), (u'explicit-hash-key', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x1033c71d0>), (u'sequence-number-for-ordering', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x1033c7210>)])
2017-04-16 19:48:35,003 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.kinesis.put-record: calling handler <function add_streaming_output_arg at 0x103039b90>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,003 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.kinesis.put-record: calling handler <function add_cli_input_json at 0x102d9fa28>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,003 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.kinesis.put-record: calling handler <function unify_paging_params at 0x102fc52a8>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,005 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /Users/as18/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/data/kinesis/2013-12-02/paginators-1.json
2017-04-16 19:48:35,005 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.kinesis.put-record: calling handler <function add_generate_skeleton at 0x102fb5668>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,006 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.kinesis.put-record: calling handler <bound method CliInputJSONArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x1033c7290>>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,006 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.kinesis.put-record: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x1033bae10>>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,006 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.kinesis.put-record.stream-name: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x102c37938>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.kinesis.put-record: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x103049110>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of u'a0135-GregorSamsa' for parameter "stream_name": u'a0135-GregorSamsa'
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.kinesis.put-record.data: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x102c37938>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.kinesis.put-record: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x103049110>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of u'whatever' for parameter "data": u'whatever'
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.kinesis.put-record.partition-key: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x102c37938>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.kinesis.put-record: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x103049110>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of u'gregor-samsa' for parameter "partition_key": u'gregor-samsa'
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.kinesis.put-record.explicit-hash-key: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x102c37938>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.kinesis.put-record.sequence-number-for-ordering: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x102c37938>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.kinesis.put-record.cli-input-json: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x102c37938>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.kinesis.put-record.generate-cli-skeleton: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x102c37938>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,007 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.kinesis.put-record: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.generate_json_skeleton of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x1033bae10>>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,008 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.kinesis.put-record: calling handler <bound method CliInputJSONArgument.add_to_call_parameters of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x1033c7290>>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,008 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2017-04-16 19:48:35,008 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2017-04-16 19:48:35,008 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2017-04-16 19:48:35,008 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /Users/as18/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2017-04-16 19:48:35,018 - MainThread - botocore.client - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: kinesis
2017-04-16 19:48:35,019 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.kinesis: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x10295cc80>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,019 - MainThread - botocore.args - DEBUG - The s3 config key is not a dictionary type, ignoring its value of: None
2017-04-16 19:48:35,022 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting kinesis timeout as (60, 60)
2017-04-16 19:48:35,022 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.kinesis.PutRecord: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x102995c80>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,023 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=PutRecord) (verify_ssl=True) with params: {'body': '{"PartitionKey": "gregor-samsa", "Data": "d2hhdGV2ZXI=", "StreamName": "a0135-GregorSamsa"}', 'url': u'https://kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/1.11.66 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/15.6.0 botocore/1.5.29', 'Content-Type': u'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'X-Amz-Target': u'Kinesis_20131202.PutRecord'}, 'context': {'client_region': u'us-west-2', 'has_streaming_input': False, 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x103530690>}, 'query_string': '', 'url_path': '/', 'method': u'POST'}
2017-04-16 19:48:35,023 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.kinesis.PutRecord: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x103530650>>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,023 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2017-04-16 19:48:35,023 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
host:kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20170417T024835Z
x-amz-security-token:"FQoDYXdzECQaDHw6n1Hfn5egvEAxeyK1AgClSVMQWgZr9dr0bRI4Xo3ocilODVE0SEymvty4OP0lSKu19DiVbpg4t+p4PAaWVQ6fQGyu9DGi5JkQZBsyW5JlZDFE8nOmpqZOddhrrc1KRWTstqtTtwNiLL18FMxQ43S5wdveS1YMsgYhEcuQtwknbN4sdYwNrDETDF4Ies/DGQqVhM0m9YX2Zu6nYZiuA8RLqf0RLpbPHDEKpLFE/uXPo4qIaGez3IZWU6Spu59Wt52Z7yQMoSlV4vJVrCoYpM7x9Eai0zZkynGD1FSW5i3knF7V0Y3dBdRBDFDSF3UXCF45+3yRFjJSvd+Se323dTzKXoZPc9AgvNl1gBLGYMY3pY5v5bGjPK4OkVF+vQkStWKQpodNe1lTGgqkniZlpNqLefiUuhtUVSTQPVBuTV/N4VA6MiiT0dDHBQ=="
x-amz-target:Kinesis_20131202.PutRecord

content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-target
337fb90b0529a5bc7eb6274475923e82c948363ff492f56071c948b24bf7181a
2017-04-16 19:48:35,023 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20170417T024835Z
20170417/us-west-2/kinesis/aws4_request
da8e3f33931941015cd88df2ef325da5488ff70fb93b55eaa46349cea9f547e0
2017-04-16 19:48:35,023 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
d7d071a403c97b018ba63477e91fe3799ae15ba895a6b216fa898ae2b19d3bdc
2017-04-16 19:48:35,025 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [POST]>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,026 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
2017-04-16 19:48:35,566 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 110
2017-04-16 19:48:35,567 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'x-amzn-requestid': 'e56a1871-3e84-a549-b404-3732842305a5', 'content-length': '110', 'x-amz-id-2': 'wartiXlESG6jqLxOILWnDGjdKF6J4Q/EXwd05kGMYbWE3nDvmjJ+U+VPahhPPrn4nw7kYKoV1MC47y4NiGTJW/UV/kuGa5wh', 'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'date': 'Mon, 17 Apr 2017 02:48:34 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'}
2017-04-16 19:48:35,567 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
{"SequenceNumber":"49572068906441151838856607983585511619092105132872040450","ShardId":"shardId-000000000000"}
2017-04-16 19:48:35,567 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.kinesis.PutRecord: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x103315510>
2017-04-16 19:48:35,568 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - No retry needed.
2017-04-16 19:48:35,568 - MainThread - awscli.formatter - DEBUG - RequestId: e56a1871-3e84-a549-b404-3732842305a5
{
    "ShardId": "shardId-000000000000", 
    "SequenceNumber": "49572068906441151838856607983585511619092105132872040450"
}
```

[AWS profile(`--profile`)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-a-single-iam-user-to-easily-access-all-your-accounts-by-using-the-aws-cli/) is used for authenticating to kinesis stream, put in `~/.aws/credentials` file

example,

```
[aws-credentials]                                                                                                                                                             
aws_access_key_id=ASIAI7QTMT4VDPQBZVSS                                                                 
aws_secret_access_key=bsYA6yZGBIRTiqfJP6V2YPOl0qTvS/bLmFdZd6bG                                         
aws_session_token="FQoDYXdzECQaDCBVBForaMuopUR+LyK1AhN4L2BZ4GCQ8prX/gtWN7vZI6pa+Ltv3xetSnDXxPCLeCAXTj12ENX/VldWfzvGPQ8NbpP2GGHPUHVNNU5bJyE6umLy/nBEDV7jJiSW2eBOD6X0d33GfJ2G893iIwFHu6IfrXiSwoQs8BuulG/ygOYZa6GWbYxagwy69HFMAtWTnGKs/L6dRikgpU6KoyVkBwfnEN0jKWcIQKd1VcED1+iIcbbDROl9P1NcxQIBnJDdV3qYk1+jLTu/hPoB8kwcKZOj/bZAnhGto3nPMb8vkQ/uLgZ5GA7e/JBhsnMLIyqrUVdd0txokHylVCajHPo//vYDaO7/NrkHeaizt2zCGkPNqm5XvCVrQvp2cJMFV850A2b7Ilq3N/KHr0iiVy5m4CHkC5BS9eqzAq8WuR3/D/mOy9slrCiH2tDHBQ=="
aws_security_token="FQoDYXdzECQaDCBVBForaMuopUR+LyK1AhN4L2BZ4GCQ8prX/gtWN7vZI6pa+Ltv3xetSnDXxPCLeCAXTj12ENX/VldWfzvGPQ8NbpP2GGHPKHVNNU5bJyE6umLy/nBEDV7jJiSW2eBOD6X0d33GfJ2G893iIwFHu6IfrXiSwoQ8pBuulG/ygOYZa6GWbYxagwy69HFMAtWTnGKs/L6dRikgpU6KoyVkBwfnEN0jKWcIQKd1VcED1+iIcbbDROl9P1NcxQIBnJDdV3qYk1+jLTu/hPoB8kwcKZOj/bZAnhGto3nPMb8vkQ/uGpZ5GA7e/JBhsnMLIyqrUVdd0txokHylVCajHPo//vYDaO7/NrkHeaizt2zCGkPNqm5XvCVrQvp2cJMFV850A2b7Ilq3N/KHr0iiVy5m4CHkC5BS9eqzAq8WuR3/D/mOy9slrCiH2tDHBQ=="
```